# Batch remove of leading space to folders

Tags: batch-file, directory

I have a folder with a bunch of subfolders with leading spaces like this:

```
" folder1" 
"  folder2" 
"  folder3"
```

I need help on removing the leading spaces.  I'm tying to create a batch file for this to mass rename.  There are too many folders to rename 1 by 1.  Thanks!

I can do it for file names but i cannot figure it out for folders

Code I use for filenames:

```
for %%A in (" *") do @for /f "tokens=*" %%B in ("%%A") do @ren "%%A" "%%B"
```

Comment: [`for /D %%A in (" *") do …`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html).

Comment: Oh man!.. why didn't i think of that.  Thanks @JosefZ

Answer (score 0):

```
for /d %%A in (" *") do @for /f "tokens=*" %%B in ("%%A") do @ren "%%A" "%%B"
```

You were missing the /d as you discovered.